# What is the right way to fetch an entry to process in my route

Tags: java, json, mongodb, apache-camel

This is my first question here, so if my question is missing some core information, please bear with me. I'll try to add the needed info as fast as possible.
I am setting up a camel route that retrieves a URL from my Database and sends this URL to a crawler, that collects some product data. The data that I receive from the crawler is then saved back to the Database into a different collection.
When I crawl another URL, that contains the same product, I want to add the newly received data to the object in my Database.

I tried to save the newly received data in a Property and then set two constants to find the corresponding item in the database. After the object is found, I want to send that received data to my processor, where I add the new Data to the retrieved object and then save it back to the DB.

```java
from("direct:myRoute")
...
    .setProperty("newItem").simple("${body}")
    .setBody().constant("{ 'name': $.name}")
    .setBody().constant("{ 'brand': $.brand}")
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database={{db}}&collection= 
         {{col}}&operation=findOneByQuery")
...
```

The expected result should be, that my Database object has the old info and the newly received info stored, but what I get is, that `{ 'name': $.name}` is no valid `BasicDBObject`, same for the brand.

**Update**

So, I found out, that setting two constants is not possible for what I wanted to achieve. I experimented a bit and was able to make it work with hard coded examples.

```
from("direct:myRoute")
...
    .setProperty("newItem").simple("${body}")
    .setBody().constant("{ 'name': 'product', 'brand': 'manufacturer'}")
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database={{db}}&collection= 
         {{col}}&operation=findOneByQuery")
...
```

But the Problem remains, that I want to set the 'name' and 'brand' as json variables extracted from the body.

**Update 2**

I changed the code around a bit and tried the following example in my code.

```
from("direct:myRoute")
...
    .setProperty("newItem").simple("${body}")
    .setBody().constant("{ 'name' : '{$.name}', 'brand' : '{$.brand}' }")
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database={{db}}&collection= 
         {{col}}&operation=findOneByQuery")
...
```

I don't get an error from this, but it does not work as expected. I hoped, that the $.name and $.brand will get replaced to the variables stored in the body, but it seems, they get used "as-is"

> 2019-11-06 13:27:43.363  INFO 2132 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] DEBUG
>   : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: String, Body: { 'name' : 
>   '{$.name}', 'brand' : '{$.brand}' }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we found a solution to this problem that works for our usecase.
We set the name and the brand as properties and used a simple to set the body with these properties.

```
from("direct:myRoute")
...
    .setProperty("newItem").simple("${body}")
    .setProperty("name").jsonpath("$.name")
    .setProperty("brand").jsonpath("$.brand")
    .setBody().simple("{'name':'${property.name}','brand':'${property.brand}'}")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database={{db}}&collection= 
         {{col}}&operation=findOneByQuery")
...
```